# Set Chinese Fonts on HTML Emails (Outlook)

Tags: email, fonts, outlook, html-email

Is it possible to set a Chinese font on HTML Emails for Outlook 2013? I want to be able to change the style of the punctuation for commas and full stop.

So it'll look similar to the Microsoft JhengHei font instead of the SimSun font.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things you can do to make sure Chinese characters display in web or email. First, some code for the email `<head>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Set HTML language attribute
    zh      = Chinese
    zh-Hans = Chinese (Simplified)
    zh-Hant = Chinese (Traditional)
-->
<html lang="zh" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <head>
        <!--
            utf-8 works for most cases, including Chinese
        -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
</html>
```

You must make sure that you **save your document in UTF-8 format** and upload the document to your server or ESP so that the format is preserved. Some editors won't do or aren't configured like this by default, so you may need to check on that.

But ultimately these fonts won't display if a user doesn't have them installed on their local system. Specifying an appropriate font stack behind `Microsoft JhengHei` will help ensure that *something* shows up.